# Redeclared extern FILE *stderr; libfprintf

Tags: c++, c, linux, msys2

I'm working porting **libfprintf v1.90.3** to Windows using **MSYS2** with
Mingw-w64.
This project use the bozorth3 algorithm from **NBIS library (NIST)**.
They made some changes to the nbis library, in the **bozorth.h** header file they re-declared the standard error

```
/* Global supporting error reporting */
extern FILE *stderr;
```

I don't understand why when compile in Linux not have a compilation error but in Windows the next error occurs:

> ../libfprint/nbis/include/bozorth.h:221:14: error: expected
> declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant   221 | extern
> FILE *stderr;

What happens in Linux that a compilation error does not occur?

Thanks.

Comment: The implementation of [`stderr` (and the other standard streams)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io#Predefined_standard_streams) is implementation defined. All that is guaranteed is that the *result* have the type `FILE *`. In other words it means that `stderr` could be a *macro* that expands into a function call or an array dereference.

Answer (score 2):

The only approved way to define `stderr` is to include `stdio.h`.

I have no idea why the library redeclares `stderr` but the solution is to remove that line, and if you then get a missing declaration of `stderr` somewhere add `#include <stdio.h>`.

They may have done the same silly thing with `errno`. If you find a declaration of `errno` later, get rid of that too.